# Mapping Data Model to Domain Model

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, lazy-loading, automapper

I am currently using AutoMapper to map my data model to my domain model, but it is causing a performance issue.  In my repository I am lazy loading the employee record.  Inside my repository when I get the employee everything is correct, but when I return `employee.ToDomain()` AutoMapper causes all of the properties for the `Employee` to be loaded, resulting in multiple queries being sent to the database causing the page to take several minutes to load.  Is there a way to prevent this from happening or should I not use AutoMapper in the Data Access Layer to map to the Domain model?

Repository:

```
public Employee GetEmployee(int employeeId)
{
    EfModels.Employee employee = Context.Employees
                    .SingleOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId);

    return employee != null ? employee.ToDomain() : null;
}
```

Employee:

```
public class Employee : BaseModel
{
    ...
    public Domain.Models.Employee ToDomain()
    {
        return Mapper.Map<Domain.Models.Employee>(this);
    }
}
```

### Update

Maps:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<EfDataAccess.EfModels.Employee, Employee>()
            .ForMember(dto => dto.Division, conf => conf.MapFrom(e => e.Division.DivisionName))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.EducationType, conf => conf.MapFrom(e => e.EducationType.Education))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.EEOJobCategory, conf => conf.MapFrom(e => e.EEOJobCategory.EEOJobCategoryName))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.EmployeeStatus, conf => conf.MapFrom(e => e.EmployeeStatus.EmployeeStatusName))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.GenderType, conf => conf.MapFrom(e => e.GenderType.Gender))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.JobTitle, conf => conf.MapFrom(e => e.JobTitle.JobTitleName))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.NationalOriginType, conf => conf.MapFrom(e => e.NationalOriginType.NationalOrigin))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.OfficeLocation, conf => conf.MapFrom(e => e.OfficeLocation.Location))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.PositionNumber, conf => conf.MapFrom(e => e.PositionNumber.Number))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.RaceType, conf => conf.MapFrom(e => e.RaceType.Race))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.TransactionType, conf => conf.MapFrom(e => e.TransactionType.Transaction))
            .ForMember(dto => dto.WorkScheduleType, conf => conf.MapFrom(e => e.WorkScheduleType.ScheduleNumberType))
            .ReverseMap();
```

Repository:

```
public Employee GetEmployee(int employeeId)
    {
        return Context.Employees
            .Where(e => e.EmployeeId== e.employeeId)
            .Project().To<Employee>().FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the problem is not AutoMapper maybe you have ef configured to select the related entities, so this can be a problem, to solve this in your dbcontext constructor add `base.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;`.

Another bad part that I see is that your are consulting first the employeed (here, you are returnig all the fields that have employee) and next doing the mapping, tosolve this, please select only the fields that you need or use the projection feautre of automapper: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions

Regards,

Comment: You don't think Lazy Loading should ever be used?

Comment: I like to have control how the related entities are included in my queries, so I have total control over the queries and get only that I need, but if you want to use it, go ahead, but use it carefully.

Comment: What's the syntax for selecting the fields?  I tried adding this: `.Select(e => new EfModels.Employee { EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId, FirstName = e.FirstName, LastName = e.LastName })` right before the `.SingleOrDefault` Line but it throws an error that it cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: Hi, try with an anonymous object: Context.Employees
 .Select(e => new { EmployeeId= e.EmployeeId, LastName = e.LastName })
        .SingleOrDefault(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId);

Comment: I tried that originally.  This gives a compile error that it cannot implicity convert type '<anonymous type: int EmployeeId, string FirstName, string LastName> ' to 'EfModels.Employee'

Comment: Yes, because you are returning and anonymous object, not an employee, so there you have to do a new convert (yes, I feel that is bad), but AutoMapper can help to do better your code using the Projection, do you try this? https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions

Comment: I looked at it.  So in the `CreateMap` I would add `.ForMember(dto => dto.*NavigationProperty*, conf => conf.MapFrom(e => e.*NavigationProperty*.Name)` for each navigational property and then I would return `context.Employees.Where(e => e.EmployeeId == employeeId).Project().To<Employee>().FirstOrDefault();` in the repository?

Comment: Yes @Andrew, try with this approach

Comment: I updated my post to show you my maps and repository.  It throws an System.StackOverflowException in the repository now.

Comment: Can you add the complete classes? I want to copy it in a local project to test

Comment: You don't have to worry about that, I'll figure it out.  Thanks for your help, you got me on the right track.

Comment: it's a pleasure Andrew!